# network link aggregation centos7 issue

Tags: linux, linux-networking, centos7, bonding

I cannot ping/connect to "Team device IP". Below are steps I took to create link aggregation on Centos7.The slave ethernet are up and i can ping successfully before .what am i missting here?

```
# nmcli con add type team con-name team1 ifname team1 config '{"runner": { "name": "loadbalance"}}'
# nmcli con modify team1 ipv4.addresses "192.168.213.100/24 192.168.213.2"
# nmcli con modify team1 ipv4.method manual
# nmcli con add type team-slave ifname eno16777736 master team1 
# nmcli con add type team-slave ifname eno33554960 master team1
# nmcli con up team1
```

Answer (score 1):

I used "nmtui" tool and got my issue solved. To run nmtui just type nmtui and get started as there are plenty of options to get off